# Show/hide div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show-hide

I am trying to show and hide content depending on which button is pressed. The next button should show content 2 and hide content 1, and previous button should do the opposite.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.button-next').click(function() {
        $("#tab-content2").addClass("show");
    });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#tab-content2 {
    display: none;
}
#tab-content2.show {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tab-content1">             
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>

<div id="tab-content2">     
    <?php the_field("experience");?>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" class="button-back">Previous</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="button-next">next</a>
```

Comment: Try this `$("#tab-content2").toggle()`  in this way, you don't even need css

Comment: Both your CSS classes are set to `display: none;`. Also you have no document ready handler around your jQuery.

Comment: jQuery does come with `.show()` and `.hide()`...

Comment: Why has no one mentioned that this is a duplicate? Just look at the related questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and don't forgot to use [document.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.button-next').click(function() {
        $("#tab-content2").toggleClass("show");
    });
});

#tab-content2.show {display:block;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a generic class for all content

```
<div class="content" id="tab-content1">             
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
<div class="content" id="tab-content2">     
    <?php the_field("experience");?>
</div>

<a href="javascript:;" class="button-back">Previous</a>
<a href="javascript:;" class="button-next">next</a>
```

So the css would be

```
.content {
    display: none;
}
```

And the Javascript

```
$('a.button-next').click(function() {
    $('.content').hide(); // To hide all other contents
    $("#tab-content2").show(); // Show the one content you want to display
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The display property of `show` is `none`.

Change it to `block`.

Also, you can just use the `.show()` or `.hide()` function instead of using classes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$('a.button-next').on('click', function() {
    $("#tab-content2").toggle("show");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div id="tab-content-holder">
    <div id="tab-content1 show">             
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="tab-content2">     
        <?php the_field("experience");?>
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="button-back">Previous</a>
<a href="#" class="button-next">Next</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button-back").click(function() {
        MenuNavigationClick(-1);
    });
    $(".button-next").click(function() {
        MenuNavigationClick(1);
    });

    function MenuNavigationClick(direction) {
        // Get current element index and toggle
        var current = $("#tab-content-holder .show");
        var index = current.index();
        current.toggleClass("show");

        // Move to next element and check for overflow
        index += 1 * direction;
        index %= $("#tab-content-holder div").length;

        // Toggle next element
        $("#tab-content-holder div:eq("+index+")").toggleClass("show");
    }
});
```

CSS

```
#tab-content-holder div {
    display: none;
}
#tab-content-holder div.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried transferring the show class on another line?

```
.show
{
    display: block;
}
```