# replacing a link with a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a newsletter signup where there is a button that says sign up and when a user clicks on it the button disappears and a textbox shows up and then when the user has clicked the submit button and it goes through the validation checks it then disappears and gets replaced with a thank you.

Can someone show me how to do it or point me in the right direction. I have searched and I'm not finding anything.

Comment: and whereisthecode.com

Comment: show what you have tried..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here, I did it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3SFDy/
Make sure to read up on jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/

jQuery:

```
$('span').hide();
$('form').hide();
$("#subscribe").click(function(){
    $("#subscribe").hide();
    $('form').show();
});
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('form').hide();
    $('span').show(); 
});
```

Comment: Downvote: Why the downvote? I could write the program because I had spare time.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a "popup" to appear.  Obviously popups are bad as those are blocked so you can use DIV.

Have a look at this

[How to display div after click the button in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957443/how-to-display-div-after-click-the-button-in-javascript)

[Show/hide div on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648439/show-hide-div-on-button-click)

[How can I hide/show a div when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308779/how-can-i-hide-show-a-div-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Hope this puts you on the right road.