# How to hide div after clicking on button?

Tags: javascript

I would like to hide the div (which is "hide-div") as soon as the user cliks on the button when there is a navigation to the same page. Please help me on this. Thanks

```
<div id="hide-div">
   <button type="button" title="test" class="button btn-small" onclick="setLocation('abc.com');"><span>'Add to Cart'</span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please follow below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648439/show-hide-div-on-button-click

Comment: In `setLocation` add `getElementById('dide-div').setAttribute('style','display:none;');`

Comment: use localStorage to preserve the value and base on the value show/hide the div ..

Comment: can you please edit above i don't understand. Sorry

Answer (score 3):

Using **Vanilla JavaScript**. Although I recommend using event handler instead of inline JS, this is in view of your code.

1. Hide the element using `style.display`
2. You can redirect the page after hiding the button using `window.location`

```js
function setLocation(loc) {
  document.getElementById('hide-div').style.display = 'none';
  window.location = loc;
}
```

```html
<div id="hide-div">
   <button type="button" title="test" class="button btn-small" onclick="setLocation('http://google.com')"><span>'Add to Cart'</span></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by simple jquery

```html
 <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(".button").click(function(){
  $("div").fadeOut();
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this in your onclick:

```
$('#hide-div').hide()
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to hide it:

```
$('#hide-div button').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have jQuery added to your page already. So, something like this maybe:

```js
 $('#hide-div .button').on('click', function() {
      $('#hide-div').hide();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide-div">
   <button type="button" title="test" class="button btn-small" onclick="setLocation('abc.com');"><span>'Add to Cart'</span></button>
</div>
```